# Loading a blob: url into a buffer

Tags: node.js

I have a file upload from a client, it sends a blob url like "blob:http%3A//192.168.99.100%3A8089/47ae2617-5f2a-4f75-8917-68c992a7ecbe"

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to convert this into a buffer. Does anybody know how to do this?